# Blade Redirection on @elseif laravel

Tags: php, laravel

is it possible to redirect a user if function returns false?

e.g

```
@if(accessFunction() == True)
  <h1>You have access, {{ Auth::user()->username }}</h1>
@elseif
  {{ Redirect('/') }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in blade.

You will need to do this in the controller method.

```
public function index()
{
  if(! AccessFunction()) {
    return redirect()->route('somewhere');
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah easy peasy. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: The function is inside a helper function that's not defined by a class, is it still possible to throw the 'use' statement?

Comment: Yes 100%, use App\Helpers\SomeUtil;  SomeUtil::accessFunction();  or you can just go with the full namespace \App\Helpers\SomeUtil::accessFunction();